# Struggling with QMK modifier keys

Tags: c, qmk, qmk-firmware

I'm getting this error when I try to use *modifier keys* on my rotary encoder like so:

```c
bool encoder_update_user(uint8_t index, bool clockwise) {
    if (index == 0) { /* First encoder */
        if (clockwise) {
            tap_code(QK_LCTL | KC_F24);
        } else {
            tap_code(QK_LCTL | KC_F23);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is the error:

```
Compiling: keyboards/planck/keymaps/dawz/keymap.c                                                  keyboards/planck/keymaps/dawz/keymap.c: In function 'encoder_update_user':
keyboards/planck/keymaps/dawz/keymap.c:68:22: error: unsigned conversion from 'int' to 'uint8_t' {aka 'unsigned char'} changes value from '371' to '115' [-Werror=overflow]
   68 |             tap_code(QK_LCTL | KC_F24);
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
keyboards/planck/keymaps/dawz/keymap.c:70:22: error: unsigned conversion from 'int' to 'uint8_t' {aka 'unsigned char'} changes value from '370' to '114' [-Werror=overflow]
   70 |             tap_code(QK_LCTL | KC_F23);
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
 [ERRORS]
 |
 |
 |
make[1]: *** [tmk_core/rules.mk:443: .build/obj_planck_rev6_drop_dawz/keyboards/planck/keymaps/dawz/keymap.o] Error 1
Make finished with errors
make: *** [Makefile:539: planck/rev6_drop:dawz] Error 1
```

The encoder works when I put in a regular keycode like KC_VOLUP or KC_VOLDOWN, but I’m trying to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F23</kbd>, <kbd>F24</kbd>, so I can use the knob as a [Voicemeeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voicemeeter) macro buttons controller.

Comment: ive also used the shortened version (C(KC_F23)) , (C(KC_F24)) also same error

Comment: [The table](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware/blob/master/docs/keycodes.md) doesn't list `KC_VOLUP`, but instead `KC_VOLU` (without the `P`), the shorthand for `KC_AUDIO_VOL_UP`.

Comment: The same for `KC_VOLDOWN`: Shorthand `KC_VOLD` for `KC_AUDIO_VOL_DOWN`. Was it changed?

Answer (score 3):

You can represent "Ctrl + (basic key)" combinations using the macro `LCTL(kc)` (and [similar macros for other mods](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/feature_advanced_keycodes%5D)), but the technicality is that this creates a 16-bit keycode. So rather than `tap_code()`, which is limited to 8-bit [basic keycodes](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/keycodes_basic), use
`tap_code16()` to tap it:

```
// Copyright 2022 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
bool encoder_update_user(uint8_t index, bool clockwise) {
  if (index == 0) {
    tap_code16(clockwise ? LCTL(KC_F24) : LCTL(KC_F23));
  } 
  return false;
}
```

See also the [QMK encoders documentation](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/feature_encoders).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use modifier keys here with encoders, you should try using [tap_code16()](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware/blob/e6ce481179e8337d34f26f0a1c0ce902c8814702/quantum/quantum.c#L149) instead of [tap_code()](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware/blob/e6ce481179e8337d34f26f0a1c0ce902c8814702/quantum/action.c#L1024).

Try this instead:

```
bool encoder_update_user(uint8_t index, bool clockwise) {
    if (index == 0) { /* First encoder */
        if (clockwise) {
            tap_code16(QK_LCTL | KC_F24);
        } else {
            tap_code16(QK_LCTL | KC_F23);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

[QMK documentation for this](https://beta.docs.qmk.fm/using-qmk/advanced-keycodes/feature_macros#register_code-16-less-than-kc-greater-than-unregister_code-16-less-than-kc-greater-than-and-tap_code-16-less-than-kc-greater-than)

Comment: The link is broken: *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at `beta.docs.qmk.fm`."*

Comment: `beta.docs.qmk.fm` was removed.

Answer (score 0):

You could break down how a key combination is pressed:

1. Hold down the modifier key
2. Press some key (usually a letter or number)
3. Release the modifier key

Then you could represent the whole process:

```c
bool encoder_update_user(uint8_t index, bool clockwise) {
    if (index == 0) { /* First encoder */
        if (clockwise) {
            register_code(QK_LCTL);   // Press and keep holding down
            tap_code(KC_F24);         // Press and release
            unregister_code(QK_LCTL); // Release
        } else {
            register_code(QK_LCTL);
            tap_code(KC_F23);
            unregister_code(QK_LCTL);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This approach seems to be dumb, but you can achieve much more complicated cases, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> or something that could hardly been done with keycodes.

I did this for one of my [self-made keyboard](https://github.com/myst729/qmk_firmware/blob/master/keyboards/dg/xtrm/keymaps/default/keymap.c#L90-L92), and it worked fine.

Comment: No, this is actually good for illustrating that the macros suggested in documentation (SS_DOWN, SS_DELAY, and SS_UP) are not the be-all and end-all. Those don't refactor well, but the sequence here does (e.g., it could use a helper function for Ctrl + X, where X is the QMK keycode, e.g., `key_CtrlAction(KC_F24)`). Even if a helper macro like KEY_CTRL_ACTION is defined it doesn't refactor (the keycode must be known at compile time (can not be part of a non-redundant highly factored set of functions for this))